laravel 10, php encrypted .env file
Previously im using laravel 7, and use php artisan env-encrypt to encrypt the value from Database in .env file
so my .env file look like
**DB_DATABASE=OUT:**eyJpdiI6ImVORk9GS003ck1Oa3BvemxLdjJlcEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVFY1Y2ZlaUJzXC9nbzBxQ3BJQVwvYUxyaTNcL0U5NyswMkVwR1wvZXp4QlE0ZkU9IiwibWFjIjoiOTgwOTIzNDFmMTM4NGY5NWY4ZGVhNGY3MWJhNzYxZDI3ZjhhYmIzZGZiNGQ1MDRjMWM1Njsdsdsdsdsdsdsd==

DB_USERNAME=OUT:eyJpdiI6ImVORk9GS003ck1Oa3BvemxLdjJlcEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVFY1Y2ZlaUJzXC9nbzBxQ3BJQVwvYUxyaTNcL0U5NyswMkVwR1wvZXp4QlE0ZkU9IiwibWFjIjoiOTgwOTIzNDFmMTM4NGY5NWY4ZGVhNGY3MWJhNzYxZDI3ZjhhYmIzZGZiNGQ1MDRjMWM1Njsdsdsdsdsdsdsd==
DB_PASSWORD=OUT:eyJpdiI6ImVORk9GS003ck1Oa3BvemxLdjJlcEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVFY1Y2ZlaUJzXC9nbzBxQ3BJQVwvYUxyaTNcL0U5NyswMkVwR1wvZXp4QlE0ZkU9IiwibWFjIjoiOTgwOTIzNDFmMTM4NGY5NWY4ZGVhNGY3MWJhNzYxZDI3ZjhhYmIzZGZiNGQ1MDRjMWM1Njsdsdsdsdsdsdsd
since i upgrade the laravel into laravel 10, i got error Invalid value specified for connection string attribute 'UID
I Follow the documentation about encrypt in .env, but i still dont understant how is work.
i try to run

php artisan env:encrypt, then it will created .env.encrypted. (its look encrypted all value in .env)

do i need to delete .env file so laravel will point to env.encrypted?

Can you do decryption? https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/configuration#decryption

Try to decrypt, do cache clear then re encrypt your env

better back up your env file first before decrypting just to make sure

Hi, i run php artisan env:encrypt, then it create file .env.encrypted with encrypted value. the .env file still the same, so after .env.encrypted created, all configuration will load based on env.encrypted? because if i shutdown the sqlserver, the username still exposed in log, for example login failed for user:ABC, meanwhile on old version, if error, in log, will show: login failed for user:OUTencryptedvaluexxxxxx

Write your composer.json. Was the .env file encrypted by a third party package? Let's restore the .env with that third party package first.
